# Open activity without click on push notification in android 13

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, android-13

Hi i am working on calling app, but when someone call to me i got notification and onclick is working fine on notification, but i want to open activity without click on push notification, how it is possible because i try many codes but nothing works in Android 13.

My Broadcastreceiver is:-

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent != null && intent.getExtras() != null) {
        Intent openActivityIntent = new Intent(context, AudioViewReceiving.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, openActivityIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
        try {
            pi.send();
        } catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This is my FirebaseMessagingService class intent:-

```
Intent openActivityIntent = new Intent(this, AudioViewReceiving.class);
            openActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(openActivityIntent);
```

Manifest is:-

```
<service
        android:name=".Notification.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver
        android:name=".AudioVideoCall.MessageReceiveBroadcast"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

This code is working is app is on Foreground but in background not, please suggest any idea for android 13, Thanks.